# change session Id in request header using Python and send http request to server using Python

Tags: c#, python, .net

I am sending a list of http request through Python. My list of request contains a login url for which I am passing username, password and other required information. Using this I am able to login to site.

`response = self.client.post('login.aspx',{parameters})`

Now after login I am getting the sessionId in cookies. I am extracting this sessionId by using the following:

`self.client.cookie.items()`

Now, how I can add this sessionId in next request header and send this request to server, so that current user's session will maintain as it is?

My execution is like.... .Net code -> execution of 1st request in 1st python file -> .net code execution -> execute 2nd request in 2nd python file -> .net code -> 3rd request in 3rd python file -> so on...so in this case session is not get maintain...thats why I am trying to pass sessionId from first request to second request header...So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from the HttpLocust class and use its client attribute to make http requests, the session should be kept alive automatically between requests which means that you do not need to explicitly set the sesssion id in the header of the next request

You can read the documentation at :
 http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#making-http-requests

Comment: Thanks for response. previously I was sending all requests in same python file. But according to requirement, I need to write one http request in one file. and after a running few lines of .Net code, I am executing python files. So that my execution is like.... .Net code -> execution of 1st request in 1st python file -> .net code execution -> execute 2nd request in 2nd python file -> .net code -> 3rd request in 3rd python file -> so on...so in this case session is not get maintain...thats why I am trying to pass sessionId from first request to second request header...So how can I do this?